Reading NFC tag action NDEF_DISCOVERED not getting in onNewIntent()
On scanning the NFC tag, device opens the chose application dialog rather than the onNewIntent callback. From log I can see the below line of code for NFC
START u0 {act=android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED dat=https://sdm.nfcdeveloper.com/... cmp=android/com.android.internal.app.ResolverActivity (has extras)} from uid 1027

I've added NDEF_DISCOVERED in manifest with enableForegroundDispatch, app is still not picking NDEF_DISCOVERED action. Below is the code I'm using
Manifest:
<intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
         <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED" />
         <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
         <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
         </intent-filter>

And in activty:
private fun enableForegroundMode() {

    val filters = arrayOfNulls<IntentFilter>(1)
    val techList = arrayOf<Array<String>>()

    filters[0] = IntentFilter()
    with(filters[0]) {
        this?.addAction(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED)//ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED
        this?.addAction(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED)//ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED
        this?.addAction(NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED)//ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED
        this?.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT)
        try {
            this?.addDataType("*/*")
        } catch (ex: IntentFilter.MalformedMimeTypeException) {
            throw RuntimeException("Check your MIME type")
        }
    }
    mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
        this, 0, Intent(
            this,
            javaClass
        ).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), FLAG_IMMUTABLE
    )
    mAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, mPendingIntent, filters, techList)
}

In onNewIntent I'm just trying log the intent action.

Basically FLAG_IMMUTABLE is wrong it should be FLAG_MUTABLE

@Andrew Changing FLAG_IMMUTABLE to FLAG_MUTABLE worked. Thanks
